# Simulink: Possible to form a Pulse Generator with amplitude between -1 and +1

Tags: simulink, pulse, amplitude

Okay - I've got Simulink up and running and I'm using the Pulse Generator with a pretty simple transfer function and the scope. I would like however to use a pulse that goes from -1 to +1 instead of from 0 to +1. Is there any way to alter the Pulse Generator block so that the amplitude is between -1 and +1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but could you change your transfer function to multiply by 2 and add -1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to take credit for this answer.  It was actually provided to my by Arnaud.

"Change the amplitude to 2 instead of 1, and then subtract 1 to the output."

I ended up following this by using an amplitude of 2, adding in a source of -1 and then summing that into the Pulse Generator.

This seemed to do the trick.

Thanks again for the insights...